# SourceTree always Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, macos, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

i use soureTree for clone ssh project.

1. i've already created ssh key
2. i've already set up gitlab ssh key setting
3. i've ssh-add "mysshkey"
4. i've ssh-add -K 'mysshkey'

when i print ssh -T ,i can make it success in the command line.
when i git clone, pull ,push in ssh ways...It still works in the command line.(terminal)

but in sourcetree still get error now:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are receiving this message because it could not authenticate you with any of the keys that were offered to it by your SSH agent. To verify this is the case, do the following:

```
ssh -T
```

This will attempt to create a connection to it for Mercurial. You should receive a response similar to the following if your key is correctly loaded.

If you do not see a message,this can be caused by a couple of factors, but these are the most common:

### - Your public key isn't loaded

To check to see if your public key is loaded, do the following:

1. Open a browser and log into origin.
2. The SSH Keys page displays. It shows a list of any existing keys.
3. If you do not have any keys listed,set one up.

### - Your identity isn't loaded into your SSH Agent

If your SSH agent doesn't know to offer a key, the connection will fail. To find out what keys your SSH Agent currently is offering, and add them, do the following:

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

Then, if you don't see your key listed, add it by

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/identity
```

For more information, check out our full Troubleshoot SSH issues guide.

### - You do not have permission to create the repository on your local filesystem

If you get the error "Permission denied", it is also possible that git or mercurial doesn't have permission to create the project folder locally. Check permissions for the directory where you're attempting to check out the project, and make sure you have write access.

```
1   Right click and "Run as Administrator".
2   Type ssh-keygen
3   Press enter.
4   It will ask you to save the key to the specific directory.
5   Press enter. It will prompt you to type password or enter without password.
6   The public key will be created to the specific directory.
7   Now go to the directory and open .ssh folder.
8   You'll see a file id_rsa.pub. Open it on notepad. Copy all text from it.
9   Go to https://gitlab.com/profile/keys .
10  Paste here in the "key" textfield.
11  Now click on the "Title" below. It will automatically get filled.
12  Then click "Add key".
```

Found that inside /var/log/gitlab/sshd/current there were multiple occurences of a message:
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys
After which I changed ownership of that file from 99:users to git:users with:
chown git:users authorized_keys

Comment: thank you, but ,i think your suggestion is not work for me,  all the step i try ,but still not working

Comment: thanks, i rewrite my ssh key of id_rsa, and it works , i think ,sourceTree default read this key name , but i don't know how to change the current key name of default

Comment: Thanks. I had multiple ssh identities and the appropriate one wasn't loaded with `ssh-add`. Ran the add command, then Sourcetree pushes again (even though sourcetree always "had" the private key loaded).

Comment: This worked great for me! The ssh agent was not having any identities, which is why the error was occurring.

Answer (score 45):

I downloaded SourceTree 2.7.6 and encountered same problem.
I think @Frankie_0927 are right, private key must be named id_rsa and must be registered in ssh agent.

for other people encountered this problem: 
try generate a pair of key following the instructions in below link:
https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/
store the private key id_rsa in ~/user/YOURUSERNAME/.ssh (path for mac) and post public key in github account.
then run

```
ssh-add -l
```

you will see

```
The agent has no identities.
```

so you run

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

to add the key into ssh agent.
after this, run

```
ssh-add -l
```

again, you will see the key is added and the problem should be solved.

Comment: very straight forward and awesome answer. Thanks

Answer (score 34):

I was able to fix it with by adding my github key to the Apple Keychain:

`ssh-add --apple-use-keychain  ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`

Comment: great! It worked. in my case, key was different - which was generated by Sourcetree. so instead of "id_ed25519", i selected my key and it worked

Comment: Thanks, it worked, as somehow source tree missed doing this.

Comment: It's works for me, but everyday I run this command, Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any way to run this with a shortcut in sourcetree via a custom action?

Comment: You sir deserve a medal! Finally fixed my problem in sourcetree.

Answer (score 1):

Sourcetree uses SSH key under folder `/User/YOURNAME/.ssh/id_rsa` to work with Git remote server.

If you generate key in another folder, the key is just valid in the terminal you execute `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` & `ssh-add`. Furthermore, it becomes invalid once the terminal closes.

Answer (score 0):

The ssh key must not have been signed in, for mac try SourceTree -> Settings -> Account -> Edit, now generate a key pair for the ssh connection.

now try pushing again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).